# C#: How do I execute a method on a property that has an attached event handler (without a stack overflow)

Tags: javascript, c#, events, c#-4.0, dom-events

Setup:
I have attached an event handler on the WebBrowser control something like this...

```
ChatInputElement.AttachEventHandler("onpropertychange", OnInputChange);
```

That part works perfect... But the site I'm messing with inputs URLEncoded information into the Input area sometime, which lacks a good human readable experience.

So I was trying to take advantage of the "onpropertychange" event, to fire a method that would URLDecode the data in the input box. Unfortunately this causes a Stack Overflow due to the "onpropertychange" event getting fired when I decode the URL...

Question:
How can I accomplish URLDecoding the data in the input box, without causing a Stack Overflow? Is there a way to detect URLEncoded material, because the input box does contain data that doesn't need to be decoded at times.

Comment: I know this comment will be a bit dated, but I noticed an error in my question I wanted to correct. I attached an event handler on an 'HtmlElement' not to the WebBrowser control. 'ChatInputElement' was the 'HtmlElement'. Sorry for any confusion. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a class-level flag inside your handler, then exit the handler if the flag is set.

Comment: don't forget to reset the flag after exiting without doing a modification. Otherwise the decoding won't fire when the user edits the field for a second time.

Comment: Thanks for your response, combined with Arjen's answer I was able to accomplish what I wanted. I've been using Stack Overflow for about a year, when I finally couldn't find an answer to my question... I decided to make an account. Glad I did. :)

Btw, would unregistering the event, making changes, and then registering the event handler again be a bad idea? It seems to work as well...

Answer (score 1):

*Store the result for comparison in subsequent handler-invocations:*

One way to prevent the loop is to store your decoded URL in a field variable before setting the property. Then, set the property. On the second invocation of the event handler, compare the stored field with the current value of the property. If it's the same, you know that you already URLDecoded it, and you exit the event handler without modifying the property.

Comment: Thanks for your response Arjen. It really helped get things moving along. :)